# Dependency Injection not working in migration files in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to use singletons for a specific class.

I did this trivially using the following in the "AppServicePrvider.php":

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Helpers\ApplicationFormHelper;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {

    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(ApplicationFormHelper::class, function ($app) {
            return new ApplicationFormHelper();
        });
    }
}
```

I then included this class in my migration file like so:

```
<?php

use App\Helpers\ApplicationFormHelper;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    private $applicationFormHelper;

    public function __construct(ApplicationFormHelper $applicationFormHelper)
    {
        $this->applicationFormHelper = $applicationFormHelper;
    }

    public function up()
    {
        //...
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

However when I execute `php artisan migrate` I get the following error, indicating that dependency injection is not working.

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]                                                             
  Type error: Argument 1 passed to CreateUsersTable::__construct() must be an instance of App\Helpers\ApplicationFor  
  mHelper, none given, called in /home/vagrant/saroia/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Mi  
  grator.php on line 335
```

Note that I have used this class is other places (e.g. in the routes file) with no problem. It seems to be only in the migrations file that this issue exists!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As @lagbox has mentioned, migration files does not seem to be resolved by IoC containers.

However it is still possible to resolve them using the app make method like so:

```
<?php

use App\Helpers\ApplicationFormHelper;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    private $applicationFormHelper;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->applicationFormHelper = app(ApplicationFormHelper::class);
    }

    public function up()
    {
        //...
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Migration files are not resolved via the IoC. They are created from the normal php 'new' mechanism. As they are not resolved from the IoC there is no dependency injection involved.

Also you don't need to bind a class to the container to allow the IoC to be able to resolve it. The IoC will try to resolve any class at any time.

> "However, there is no need to bind classes into the container if they do not depend on any interfaces. The container does not need to be instructed on how to build these objects, since it can automatically resolve such "concrete" objects using PHP's reflection services."

[Laravel 5.2 - Service Container - Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/container#binding)

So unless you really need a singleton, you don't have to declare any binding for the IoC to resolve that particular class.

Comment: Yeah I need it to be singleton. So how would I perform dependency injection then?